# How to solve first order partial differential equations.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, intuition

What is a general recipe for solving a first order PDE of the form $a(x,y,u)u_x + b(x,y,u)u_y = c(x,y,u)$, where we know $u = f(x,y)$ on some line $h(x,y) = 0$?

It would also be very helpful if somebody could provide an intuitive explanation to complement the recipe.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What do you know of the method of characteristic curves?

Comment: You start by solving $dx/a(x,y,u)=dy/b(x,y,u)$ to get characteristic curves, but I don't know what to do afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the the Lagrange auxiliary equations to convert PDE to a nonlinear (actully depends on the given equation) system of first order ODEs. Let me say a couple of words for that. The Lagrange equations are $\frac{dx}{a(x,y,u)}=\frac{dy}{b(x,y,u)}=\frac{du}{c(x,y,u)}$. From this you have 
\begin{equation}
\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{b(x,y,u)}{a(x,y,u)}\qquad (1)
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{c(x,y,u)}{a(x,y,u)}\qquad (2)
\end{equation}

The system (1)-(2) is not easy to solve in general. Once solving this system you find $y=y(x,c_1)$ and $u=u(x,c_2)$ where $c_1$ and $c_2$ are any integration constants. Eliminating these $c_1$ and $c_2$ you come up with a general solution (called integral surface) given implicitly $G(x,y,u)=0$ for some continuosly diferentiable function $G$. If you have a Cauchy (or initial-value problem) $c_1$ and $c_2$ can be determined by this data.

Comment: If it is easier one can also solve  $\dot x(s)=a$, $\dot y(s)=b$, $\dot u(s)=c$ with some free parameter $s$. Note that you can multiply the original PDE with a factor without changing the solution set.